# Change test runner working directory

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, resharper

Is it possible to change the working directory when running/debugging unit tests using the integrated test runner that comes as part of resharper?

Answer (score 7):

Turns out you can;

```
 Main Menu > Reshaper > Options > Tools > Unit Testing > Run Tests From
```

You also need to change the output dir of the test project of course.

The problem with this is it's a global change rather than per project. I have now fixed my issue by changing the output dir of the system under test to the unit test output dir.